# Probabilities, computing when at least one thing happen

Tags: probability

Events $A$ and $B$ are independent. We know their probabilities, $P(A)=0.7, P(B)=0.6$. Compute $P(A \cup B)$? Can this be solved somehow?

Comment: Do you mean they are independent of each other?

Comment: Yes. I'm non-native in English.

Comment: That's fine. It's important to be precise of course! :)

Comment: Hint: P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B). (2.) Since A and B are independent, one knows P(A and B). Ergo.

Comment: @SimonHayward *Independent* is all right. *Independent of each other* does not exist.

Comment: Yes, should say independent. Original post said A and B do not depend on each other, which I was attempting to correct (badly).

Comment: @student While we are dealing with terminology questions, please note that what you call *consequences* are really *events*.

Comment: @did Thanks. I try to remember that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so since $A$ and $B$ are independent we have $P(A \cap B)= P(A).P(B)$. Further, basic algebra of sets tells us that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

You should be able to take it from here!

Comment: Okay. It is 0.88.

Comment: Sorry, I try to remember. :)

Answer (score 0):

If two events, A and B are independent then the joint probability is
P(A AND B) = P(A)XP(B) = 0.7X0.6 = 0.42

fOR, P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A AND B) = 0.7+0.6-0.42 = 0.88.

Comment: Why give the answer away completely? That's not hugely helpful for learning.....   Also, do you know Latex formatting?

Comment: @SimonHayward Let's cut Maitreyi some slack. This is a first answer on math.SE from someone who has asked seven questions of the kind typically asked by a beginning student of probability. I am glad that Maitreyi has learned something useful and is willing to contribute this knowledge to this forum, elementary though this calculation is.

Comment: FWIW I wasn't the one doing the down voting.